# Сode with sms for ios

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sms

I know that with `iOS 12` you have the opportunity to read sms with code by keyword.

```
keyboardType = .oneTimeCode
```

**Is it possible to do this for earlier versions of ios, or is there an alternative?**

Comment: There is no such possibility for earlier versions of iOS. Only iOS12+

Answer (score 0):

This characteristic is reserve for iOS 12.0+ as stated in here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/2980930-onetimecode

> static let oneTimeCode: UITextContentType
>
> SDKs
>
> iOS 12.0+ Mac Catalyst 13.0+ tvOS 12.0+

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of alternative to this? So that the code from SMS does not enter manually

Comment: Honestly I don't think so, because of iOS Sandbox. Remember that every app runs in a close system and unless you hack iOS you will not be able to access the sms of a users. And frankly that is not bad because if you could then malicious software also could access sms and that's sensitive data.